# Redirecting page using ajax and php to two different locations

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Have a problem with the redirection,I have 2 buttons and want to redirect differently but the code is not working.

Please provide a solution or any mistake in my code.

here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form method="post">
<?php
include("./config.php");
         $sql="Select cat_id,cat_name from category";
             $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysql_error()."no data");
            ?>
            <select name="cat" id="cat">
                        <option value=0>Select Category</option>
                    <?php
                        while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
                     {
                 ?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $row[0];?>"><?php echo $row[1];}?></option>
                    </select>
      </form>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 function makeAjaxRequest(cate){
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          data: { cat: cate }, 
          url: "fetchmenu.php",
          success: function(data) {
           $('#showresult').html(data);
          }
        });
      }

 $("#cat").on("change", function(){
        var id = $(this).val();
          makeAjaxRequest(id);

      });
 </script>
<div id="showresult">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Above code was for selecting a category and now on category selection I will get the items from database with two options edit and delete button.

fetchmenu.php

```
<?php

include("config.php"); 
$ct = $_REQUEST["cat"];
$sql="Select item_id,item_name,item_image from item_list where c_id='$ct'";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysql_error()."no data");
            echo  "    <form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' action=''>
            <table cellspacing='5px' width='auto' align='center' style='margin-left:5%'>

";             while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
             {

    echo "<tr>   
        <td style='width:100px;'>
        <img src='".$row[2]."'alt='' name='upload' height='100px' width='100px'/></td>
        <td>
        '".$row[1]."'</td>";

      echo "<td style='vertical-align:middle;'><button type='button' name='ect' value='ect_".$row[0]."' style='margin-left:80px;border:none;background-color:#ff7143; color:#353534;height:30px;width:100px; margin-bottom:20px;' onclick='editmenu.php'>Edit</button>   </td>
";      
  echo "
       <td>
       <button type='button' name='dlet' id='dlt' value='dlt_".$row[0]."' style='margin-left:80px;border:none;background-color:#ff7143; color:#353534;height:30px;width:100px;margin-bottom:20px;' onclick='deletemenu.php'>Delete</button>";}
       echo "    
       </td>
        </tr>       
        </table>
        </form>";

  ?>
```

How do I redirect them to 2 different pages,its not working through ajax and also directly,its not working i.e when I write onclick="editmenu.php".
please somebody give a solution,I'm really stuck.

Comment: Ajax is typically for when you *don't* want to redirect. I also don't see a redirection attempt in the code you posted.

Comment: That's partially true, you can do it still, but need to call it the old way. Allow me to write it out for you.

Comment: Will be glad to have it.

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: If you are talking about "Edit" & "Delete" buttons then simply use <a href=editmenu.php>Edit</a> and <a href=deletemenu.php>Delete</a>

Comment: Thanks all for the effort but I used something like 2 different forms for 2 different buttons with different action buttons and its working fine now.

Comment: @VinitaVaswani by the way, your query error handling is buggy. You're trying to use `mysql_error` even though you make your query with `mysqli_query`.  To get the error, do `mysqli_error($con)` instead.

Comment: thanks RiggsFolly for the coding standards, thanks ZeJur and BeetleJuice for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to put a timer inside of a trigger function like:

```
{!--calls after webpage is ran--}
<button onclick="callme()">Click me</button>

<script>
//call to trigger timer
function callme(){
setInterval(redirect, 10000);
}

//actual run function
function redirect() {
location.href = "fetchmenu.php";
}
</script>
```

Comment: that's javascript, but its not ajax

Comment: the concept follows the same methodology, and you could use the ajax call method to put the url being directed to into the address spot ;) ;)